# Add the values in a range of cells, whose adjacent cells contain same value

Tags: excel

I have multiple columns of data.
What I need is that excel should find all the cells containing similar values in first column and add the values present in the adjacent column and keep one line and delete all the lines with similar values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPgr9.png

In this Image, I need excel to check the values under shipment tab and for all same values, add the net weight values. After that , i need to keep one line containing shipment no, net weight and rest of the fields but delete the repeating rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new table (same columns) with a single row for each unique shipment number. Then you can use a `sumif` formula to sum the "Total Weight" column based on the shipment number as the criteria.